# How to mount a network drive with authentication at startup on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, security, mount, boot

I need to keep a network drive mounted at all times. I figured out how to mount it at startup, but this requires a password that changes every 3 months.

How can I get around having to change the password in the startup script every three months?

And, even better, how can I avoid having the password in the startup script altogether?

Comment: Put the password in your keychain, change it every three months, and be glad that it doesn't change every week. ;)

Comment: In all seriousness, though, you're either going to need the password stored _somewhere_ where that script can use it, or you're going to need some other way to authenticate to the network volume.